# Good way for splitting a page into small pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC3 and I would like to be sure the way I do is a good one. Let's say I have a page containing different things such as some header info at the top and some detail info (footer) at the bottom. I prefer to create partial pages to split all these things in small pages (easy to manage).

Below is an example page:

[image]

Here is the way I cut my page into small pages.

[image]

This way of doing is (for me at least) easy to understand and to manage.

Here is my Detail.cshtml page

```
@model DocumentManager.ViewModels.SuiteDetailViewModel
<div class="detail-header-toolbar">     @Html.Partial("DetailHeaderToolbar")            </div>
<div class="detail-header-affaire">     @Html.Partial("DetailHeaderAffaire")            </div>
<div class="detail-footer-suite">       @Html.Partial("DetailFooterTabs", Model.Suite)  </div>
<div class="detail-script">             @Html.Partial("DetailScript", Model.Suite)      </div>
```

I place all my scripts in one page for convenience (DetailScript.cshtml).

I would like your opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion splitting the page into smaller parts is a good way of organizing your code.

You should take a look at [Layouts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) - using a layout will help you minimize duplicated code and apply consistent look & feel.

You're right to pass smaller models to your partial views.

The only change I would make would be to move divs with classes (`<div class="detail-header-toolbar">`) inside partial views - they are really a part of the partial view.